# Mysql to Mysqli conversion issue: login

Tags: php, mysqli

I had a simple login script that worked perfectly fine under mysql and im currently trying to port it to mysqli and i just cant get it to work.

```
login($username, $password) {
  $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pw', 'db');
  $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);
  $username = sanitize($username);
  $password = md5($password);
  $loginquery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password = '$password'";
  $count = mysqli_query($link, $loginqueryquery);
  $countarray = mysqli_fetch_array($count, MYSQLI_BOTH);
  $countarrayres = $countarray[0];
  if($countarrayres == 1) {return true ;} else {return false ;}
}
```

ive tried it all on a test page: i set $username = test, and $password = test, which tallies with my "test" user in my db. this produces a $countarrayres = 1 when i print it. i also get a print of 0 for the same if i change either the pw or username to something non-existant so its suggests it works, but im baffled.

the page this script acts in is simply:

```
$login = login($username, $password);
     if( $login === false ) { "wrong password/username bro"; } else { //log in based on session user_id;}
```

ive tried changing false to true but i continue to get the "wrong password/username bro" message so it would suggest theres a bigger problem than the function perhaps? im miffed as to whats going on here, because the only thing thats changed is the mysql -> mysqli functions, nothing else. any ideas?

EDIT: $test was a typo, it is actually $login in my script. sorry chaps.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What goes wrong where? What does `mysqli_error()`  have to say about the query? What does the query contain when you output it and what happens if you run the query in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: it doesnt let me log in, and shows the message "wrong username/password" every time, whether the combination is correct or wrong. mysqli_error() wont output anything for me. 

$count outputs:

      mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ) 

and $countarray outputs 

      Array ( [0] => 1 [COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)] => 1 )

So im able to extract the number one from that with ease. it just doesnt want to work in the function. if i run the query with test in myphpadmin as the variables i get 1, the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

In your test part you are setting the variable $test to the result of login() but then testing if $login is false...

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = login($username, $password);
     if( $login === false ) { "wrong password/username bro"; } else { //log in based on session user_id;}
```

should be

```
$test = login($username, $password);
     if( $test === false ) { "wrong password/username bro"; } else { //log in based on session user_id;}
```